# Displaying formatted load average

Tags: bash, text-processing

Hey so im trying to make a command file that displays the processor load as an star (`*`) and writes it to the file every 10 seconds. load = 1 = 10 stars (`*`), and if load > 0.5 then it also records the time and date before the star sequence.

Comment: Sure. Show us the work you've done so far and we'll fill in the blanks.

Comment: Do you know how to get the load? Do [arithmetic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) in the shell? [Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
function doload {
        load="$(uptime | rev | cut -d $' ' -f 3 | rev | tr ',' '.')" #load average over the last 1 minute
        var="$(bc <<< "${load::4}*10" | cut -d '.' -f 1)"
        if [[ -z "$var" ]]; then echo ""; return; fi
        if (( $(echo "${load::4} > 0.5" | bc -l) )); then
                echo -n "$(date) "
                for ((i=0; i < "$var"; i++)); do
                        echo -n \*
                done
                echo ""
        else
                for ((i=0; i < "$var"; i++)); do
                        echo -n \*
                done
                echo ""
        fi
}

while true; do
        doload
        sleep 10
done
```

at of *0.19* load it will print you 1 `*` and at a load of *1.79*  17`*`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I dont really have any knowledge in bash :\ just needed this to finnish my class! THANK You!

Comment: @k4l4sh4s if a answer solve your problem, mark it please as solved.